# array of objects passed to controller,view and displaying them in the view as a list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have to retrieve multiple colums from my table called user_login and display it in the view.
i am receiving it in a array of objects and i am facing problems in displaying the data.
my model is

```
$this->db->select('username,country,designation');
$this->db->from('user_login');

$this->db->join('friends','friends.friend_id=user_login.id');



$query = $this->db->get();
```

my query dump is

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 5 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 3 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.5.5-10.1.19-MariaDB [server_version] => 50505 [stat] => Uptime: 4836 Threads: 1 Questions: 151 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 19 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 13 Queries per second avg: 0.031 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 41 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )
```

please let me know what should i pass to controller and what should be passed to veiw.i know how to display elements from objects of array using foreach loops.but whatever i try ,it gives undefined error in the view.
my controller is

```
$result=$this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id);






$this->load->view('following',$result);
```

Comment: `$query->result()` will contain the data for the user. You should return the result from the model instead returning all the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store result in a varibale using result_array() function

```
<?php

$this->db->select('username,country,designation');
$this->db->from('user_login');

$this->db->join('friends','friends.friend_id=user_login.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the $user_id? Is it necessary? I hope this is what are you asking for.

**IN CONTROLLER**

```
$data['result'] = $this->Main_Model->display_following()->result_array();
$this->load->view('following',$data);
```

**IN VIEW**

```
<?php
foreach($result as $res){
    echo $res['username'].$res['country'].$res['designation']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: but i can't see any WHERE condition in it, i think this query is used to show all table record

Answer (score 0):

Model : (Following Amit Gaud's answer)

`return $query->result_array();`

Controller:

`$data['result'] = $this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id);
$this->load->view('following',$data);`

View :

```html
<ul>
<?php 
      if(isset($result) && is_array($result) && count($result)>0)
      {
         foreach($result as $key=>$value)
         { ?>
            <li><?php echo $value['yourfield']; ?></li>
   <?php }
      }
      else
      { ?>
          <li>No Results</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```